# How do I/Can I make VisualForce Page Block appear on Edit Page?

Tags: visualforce

We are still in Classic (Lightning move in the near future). We have need of a description/help text that is longer than what is available in the help text hover bubbles. Particularly on the edit page.

I created a VisualForce page block that sits nicely as guidance above the fields that need to be entered. It makes no sense however to have the guidance after first save.

How can I expose/make available the VisualForce page block guidance on the edit page at point of creation?

Comment: You could perform this logic based on whether or not the current record has an `Id` or not and show the tip if it has no `Id` value. If you provide some code, we can probably help make that happen, if you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you!

<apex:page standardController="Goal_Plan__c" tabStyle="Goal_Plan__c">
 <apex:pageBlock > 
<apex:pageblocksection>
<h1> Smart Goals </h1> 
<p>Guidance on creating a Smart Goal Text - shortened here for space!</p>
</apex:pageblocksection>
 </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>

Comment: Rebecca, you can answer your own question down below - I'd love to see your solution and I'm sure other people would too!

Answer (score 0):

I would love to say I answered this myself - but I had some help from David Cheung from Idealist Consulting. To quote:

"Custom VF components can't be displayed in edit mode on a standard page layout. You would have write a custom Visualforce page or Lightning component to replicate the entire page layout for the editing function and override the Edit button so that it calls the VF page / Lightning component."

I haven't yet written the code - but when I do I will post that as an edit/follow up answer.